Get Request with Axios in React Native
Please help me and guide me how to solve the following problem.
I want to consult any "RUC" number and have the textinputs completed with the values ​​returned by the request and if it does not return I will show some toast or console.
I want to use the api of "https://apis.net.pe/", I already have a token. I provide my code, I am getting the error with code 422.
api/api.tsx:

import axios from 'axios';

const API_URL = 'https://api.apis.net.pe/v2/sunat/ruc/full';
const API_TOKEN = 'MY_API_TOKEN';

const getRuc = async (ruc) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}?numero=${ruc}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${API_TOKEN}`,
        },
      });
      return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export { getRuc };


supplierRegisterScreen.tsx:
import { Alert, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { COLORS, SPACING, INPUTSTYLES } from '../styles/gstyles'
import InputWithSearchButton from '../components/InputWithSearchButton';
import ButtonPrimary from '../components/ButtonPrimary';
import Toast from 'react-native-toast-message';
import {getRuc} from '../api/api';


const SupplierRegisterScreen = () => {

  //estado para indicar si se esta cargando la información
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  //estado para almacenar la informacion del proveedor
  const [doc, setDoc] = useState();
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');
  const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
  const [district, setDistrict] = useState('');
  const [province, setProvince] = useState('');  
  const [department, setDepartment] = useState('');
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');



  //Función para consultar a una API y obtener informacion del proveedor según el RUC
  const searchRuc = async () => {
    //mostrar indicar de carga
    // setLoading(true);

    const ruc = doc;
    const data = await getRuc(ruc)
    // Update the form fields with the retrieved data
    setFullName(data.razonSocial);
    setAddress(data.direccion);
    setDistrict(data.distrito);
    setProvince(data.provincia);
    setDepartment(data.departamento);
    setPhone(data.telefono);
    setEmail(data.email);
  }

  const saveSupplier = ()=>{
//  codigo para guardar el proveedor
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <Text>Complete los siguientes campos para registrar un nuevo proveedor.</Text>

      <InputWithSearchButton
        placeholder={'RUC'}
        value={doc}
        onChange={(doc)=>{setDoc(doc)}}
        onPress={() => { searchRuc() }}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={INPUTSTYLES.inputWhite}
        placeholder="Nombre / Razón Social"
        placeholderTextColor={COLORS.black}
        value={fullName}
        onChangeText={(fullName) => setFullName(fullName)}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={INPUTSTYLES.inputWhite}
        placeholder="Dirección"
        placeholderTextColor={COLORS.black}
        value={address}
        onChangeText={(address) => setAddress(address)}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={INPUTSTYLES.inputWhite}
        placeholder="Distrito"
        placeholderTextColor={COLORS.black}
        value={district}
        onChangeText={(district) => setDistrict(district)}
      />
       <TextInput
        style={INPUTSTYLES.inputWhite}
        placeholder="Provincia"
        placeholderTextColor={COLORS.black}
        value={province}
        onChangeText={(province) => setProvince(province)}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={INPUTSTYLES.inputWhite}
        placeholder="Departamento"
        placeholderTextColor={COLORS.black}
        value={department}
        onChangeText={(department) => setDepartment(department)}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={INPUTSTYLES.inputWhite}
        placeholder="Teléfono"
        placeholderTextColor={COLORS.black}
        value={phone}
        onChangeText={(phone) => setPhone(phone)}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={INPUTSTYLES.inputWhite}
        placeholder="Email"
        placeholderTextColor={COLORS.black}
        value={email}
        onChangeText={(email) => setEmail(email)}
      />

      <ButtonPrimary
        onPress={() => { saveSupplier() }}
        title="Guardar"
        disabled={loading}
        loading={loading}
      />

    </View>
  )
}

export default SupplierRegisterScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    padding: SPACING.space_12,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.gray2,
    flex: 1
  },
  flex: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
})

InputWithSearchButton.js:
import React from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import { COLORS, BORDERRADIUS, SPACING } from '../styles/gstyles';

const InputWithSearchButton = ({ placeholder, onPress, value, onChange }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                keyboardType='numeric'
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onPress}>
                <Image source={require('../assets/icons/icon_search.png')} style={styles.icon} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = {
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    input: {
        backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
        color: COLORS.black,
        borderRadius: BORDERRADIUS.radius_8,
        flex: 1,
        marginRight: SPACING.space_10,
        paddingLeft: SPACING.space_12,
        marginVertical: SPACING.space_4,
    },
    button: {
        backgroundColor: COLORS.orange,
        padding: SPACING.space_12,
        borderRadius: BORDERRADIUS.radius_8,
    },
    icon: {
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
    },
};

export default InputWithSearchButton;```


What's in the actual response body? Try console.error(error.response?.data)
